# How can I check if a class has operator<< defined for it?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, enable-if

How can I check if `std::cout << myClass;` is valid? I'd like to do something like:

```
class Logger {
 public:
  // Some kind of enable_if(operator<< doesn't exist)
  void printMyClass(MyClass& my_class) {
    std::cout << "Got a myclass" << std::endl;
  }   

  // Some kind of enable_if(operator<< exists)
  void printMyClass(MyClass& my_class) {
    std::cout << "Got a myclass: " << my_class << std::endl;
  }   

};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980508/best-way-to-check-for-existence-of-an-operator-in-c11

Comment: Not a dupe, because operator<< doesn't have to be a member function

Comment: Instantiate and step through it with visual studio debugger

Comment: @Callat I'm pretty sure OP want's to know at compile time and have the compiler resolve which function to call based on that knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, you're right the second is what I was looking for. I voted to self-close as dupe